# Почему код не работает?

Tags: python, aiogram-3.x

Товарищи, можете подсказать почему не работает? Все пишет, ошибок нет, но при нажатии кнопки финиша, ничего не происходит, все остальное нормально работает.

```
import asyncio
import logging
import sys

from aiogram.enums import ParseMode
from aiogram.fsm.context import FSMContext
from openpyxl import *
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, types, F
from aiogram.filters import CommandStart

TOKEN = "***"
dp = Dispatcher()
wb = Workbook()
lst = wb.active
a1 = 1
a2 = 1
v = 1
ord1 = []


# # Добавление листа 'Sheet' в конец (по умолчанию).
# list1 = wb.create_sheet("List")
# # Добавим лист 'Sheet' в первую позицию.
# # Если "List" существует, добавим цифру 1 в конец имени
# list2 = wb.create_sheet("List", 0)
# # Добавим лист "Another list" на позицию 1
# wb.create_sheet(index=1, title="Another list")
# # Вывод на экран названий листов
# print(wb.sheetnames)

@dp.message(CommandStart())
async def cmd_start(message: types.Message):
    kb = [
        [
            types.KeyboardButton(text="Финиш")
        ],
    ]
    keyboard = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(
        keyboard=kb,
        resize_keyboard=True
    )
    await message.answer("Фото + подпись в формате комментарий.количество.цена", reply_markup=keyboard)


@dp.message()
async def echo(message: types.Message):
    pass


@dp.message()
async def state1(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    global v
    a0 = message.text.split('.')
    a2 = a0[0]
    a3 = a0[1]
    a4 = a0[2]
    a1 = message.photo
    lst.append(a1, a2, a3,a4)
    c1 = lst.cell(row=v, column=1)
    c1.value = a2
    v += 1


@dp.message(F.text.lower == "финиш")
async def without_puree(message: types.Message):
    await message.reply("Заказ принят")



async def main() -> None:
    # Initialize Bot instance with a default parse mode which will be passed to all API calls
    bot = Bot(TOKEN, parse_mode=ParseMode.HTML)
    # And the run events dispatching
    await dp.start_polling(bot)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO, stream=sys.stdout)
    asyncio.run(main())
```

Comment: lower -> lower()

Answer (score 1):

Согласно [документации](https://docs.aiogram.dev/en/latest/dispatcher/filters/magic_filters.html#attribute-modifiers-string-manipulations) замените проверку хендлера

```py
@dp.message(F.text.lower() == "финиш")
```